# Box Api and php curl: help passing nested values

Tags: php, curl, box-api

I'm getting silly!
Can somebody help me converting this call into a proper php curl function?

```
$result=shell_exec('curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/'.$xml->item_id.' -H "Authorization: Bearer '.$row_boxitems['access_token'].'" -d \'{"shared_link": {"access": "open"}}\' -X PUT  2>&1');
```

Apparently the problem lies behind the nested parameters in -d. I have tried 'em all!!!

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What about to use `json_encode` to generate the values first.

Try

```
$data = array(  
    'shared_link' => array(
        'access' -> 'open'
    )
);

$data = json_encode($data);  
$result=shell_exec('curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/'.$xml->item_id.' -H "Authorization: Bearer '.$row_boxitems['access_token'].'" -d '. $data .' -X PUT  2>&1');
```